# Why type float converted to type double automatically, no other operation

Tags: c++, double

I use Visual Studio 2017. C++. When I try to compile this code, a conversion error occurs. I want to know why the "heavy" variable is converted to double?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

struct CandyBar
{
char band[20];
float heavy;
int kaluli;
};
using namespace std;
int main()
{

CandyBar *snack = new CandyBar[3];
snack[0] = {"snack A", 2.3, 350 };
snack[1] = {"snack B", 3.3f, 450 };
snack[2] = {"snack C", 4.3f, 550 };
int i = 0;
while (i < 3)
{
    cout << "band is " << snack[i].band << endl;
    cout << "heavy is " << snack[i].heavy << endl;
    cout << "kaluli is " << snack[i].kaluli << endl;
    cout << "=====================================" << endl;
    i++;
}
delete[] snack;

return 0;
}
```

Because I use Chinese-Version visual studio, so the error displays as chinese like this, sorry for not display whole error messages.
[image]

Comment: double != float

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Also please read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/), and all of http://idownvotedbecau.se/ to learn some reasons your question might be down-voted. Finally, please [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please see [ask] and [The perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/).

Comment: Use `2.3f` to indicate that you want it to be a `float` literal.

Comment: Please post the text of the error and your code snippet (not image) into your question.

Comment: On an unrelated note, if you want an array where the size is known at compile-time, don't use `new[]` and `delete[]` to manage that array. Instead create an *actual* array, as in `CandyBar snack[3];`. Or, if you ever need to pass the array to a function then I recommend [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) instead: `std::array<CandyBar, 3> snack;` And don't use character-arrays for strings, use [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) instead.

Comment: Actually, *always* use `std::array` instead of C arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the code shown you would typically get the following warning:

```
warning C4838: conversion from 'double' to 'float' requires a narrowing conversion
```

This is because the `2.3` is a literal and is interpreted to mean `double`. If you wish to specify `2.3` as a float then you can be explicit and write `2.3f` and there won't be a narrowing conversion.

---

The [format](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/floating_literal)  includes an optional suffix.

The suffix, if present, is one of `f`, `F`, `l`, or `L`. The suffix determines the type of the floating-point literal:

- (no suffix) defines double
- `f` `F` defines float
- `l` `L` defines long double

Comment: thank you for your reply. from your words,I have a new knowledge:  [some numbers like 2.3 will be interpreted to mean double if I do not add specific suffix]

Comment: @海拥抱 You're very welcome.